# Best place to clean up files in linux start up

Tags: linux, boot

I have several RHEL Linux servers, but sometimes when the servers hangup, in the restart, a few services don't start because uncleaned lock files.

Where is the best place to put a cleanup to be executed in the startup in order to remove that files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about Run Levels [`here`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1274).

You should be able to delete these files before the services try running by adding a symlink to a cleanup script (essentially an `rm` command) in `rc1.d`.